# собрался на встречу

Tags: словоупотребление

I can't figure out what the speaker is trying to say in this statement with ***собрался на встречу***:

> Я не могу долго говорить! Я **собрался на встречу**, которая начнётся
>   через пять минут. Могу я тебе перезвонить позже?

Comment: "I'm going to a meeting"

Comment: "собираться / собраться" does not only mean that a person is planning to do somthing, but implies that some physical or intellectual effort is being made to gradually make these intentions more likely to come true. Here, "packing up" is a good metaphor (if you look up other meanings of "собираться"). By no means the most obvious choice, it allows this past tense use to express that attending a meeting was planned well ahead, and the person is actually quite ready to leave.

Comment: Come to think of it, does not imply, but *may* imply. This leaves it a bit ambiguous: a person may tell you "Я собираюсь" to strategically disguise the fact that they haven't really decided yet, but, you know, they are more likely to follow this course of action than not. And are too polite to admit that they haven't given it much thought ^_^.

Comment: @CocoPop A couple of your recent question texts look like a poor translation from English, or as if they were written by Russians living in the US.

Comment: @Shady_arc: We express this same nuance in English by changing the preposition from "to" to "into" and only use this at the last moment if someone attempts to hold us up or needs something right away. Thanks for your wonderful explanations :)

Comment: @jwalker: Good observation! These are actually all from the same person - a Russian living in Shanghai (of all places). The fact that they sound strange to me too, tells me that my Russian must be improving :)

Comment: Sadly, it is not that easy for a native speaker living far from their home country to maintain their language the same as it was in the native environment. It is even harder to admit that after many years you are starting to sound a bit foreign for a native who lives in a country where the language is spoken. Reminds me of one Swedish student who lost her local accent after 5 years in Russia. People in her hometown kept asking what region she comes from :). Still, better than sounding foreign.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`собрался на встречу` does sound a bit awkward in this context. I guess the speaker omitted a verb here to signify that they do not have time even to phrase this sentence correctly. The correct form would be:

```
 Я собрался пойти на встречу
 Я собрался поехать на встречу
```

Where `Я собрался` is used as `I am ready to ...`

```
 I am ready to go to a meeting
 I am about to go to a meeting
 I am going into a meeting
```

Comment: They are both correct, though "пойти" would make it less natural in context (here the sentence should be a valid explanation of why the person is busy, not a recollection of the person's past plans — "пойти" makes it longer and does not add anything) Remember, intention to ***go*** somewhere is one of the meanings of the verb by itself (which is not only supported by real life usage but by dictionary examples, too). You may specify that you intend to "go" somewhere, but that's completely up to the speaker.

Comment: Not at all. It's what I might say if someone called me at my workplace at exactly the moment when I stood up ('собрался') in order to go to a meeting room.

Comment: Aha! I know exactly what this means now. In this situation, we use "into a meeting" instead of "to a meeting" to express that we're short on time: "I can't talk, I'm going INTO a meeting in 5 minutes." Thanks!

Comment: At my job, we don't use the word 'совещание'. Sounds too heavy, Sovietesque. We say 'встреча'. Don't know, however, if that's so in other companies.

Answer (score 3):

Your guy was trying to say that he's about to leave for a meeting. **Собрался на встречу** literally means that a person prepared himself to go for a meeting and when used in a conversation means that the person is about to do something. This might not make sense for a non-native speakers at first but it totally does.

Think of it that way: I'd bet you heard an expression **Я уже собрался уходить**, it means "I'm about to be off". **Я собрался *[to do something]*** you say when you are about to start *[to do something]*.

I hope this would clarify your understanding of the situation. Good day, sir!

Answer (score 3):

Yes, "собраться" mean "be prepared for". And, in my opinion, it come from "собрать вещи (сумку)" (not sure in English variant for this, think it's like "put staff in a bag"). For example, one of my favorite idiomatic expression "нищему собраться - только подпоясаться".

Answer (score 0):

It literaly means "I have gotten ready [to go] to a meeting." In English we would say "I'm am ready to go to a meeting." or "I'm all set to go to a meeting."